# How to POST SPARQL to Virtuoso?

Tags: post, sparql, virtuoso

I am using two different `HTTP POST` utilities ([poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) out of Firefox as well as `Python` [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) API) to post a simple `SPARQL` insert to `Virtuoso`.

My URL is: `http://localhost:8890/sparql`

My request parameters are:

```
default-graph-uri: <MY_GRAPH>
should-sponge: soft
debug: on
timeout: 
format: application/xml
save: display
fname:
```

I put the actual SPARQL (`INSERT DATA { GRAPH...`) in the content of the message.

I tried different content types, none of which worked. I do get 200 but the response is in HTML even though the above parameter set specifies `application/xml`, however, no data is inserted. When I try content type of `text/turtle`, I get 409 Invalid Path, which is also referenced in [this post](https://www.mail-archive.com/virtuoso-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07015.html).

I can successfully do `HTTP GET`, however, that has a payload length limitation which I would like to exceed for performance reasons. The only difference with the GET is that the SPARQL goes in the URL under `query` parameter and the POST **should** enable a much larger payload in the message content, by including multiple triples in the same request, not just one (I have 100s of 1000s of inserts). I was trying to follow [this documentation page](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlprotocolendpoint/#rdfsupportedprotocolendpointurisparqlauthex).

Comment: You can keep posting here, but it's worth noting that Virtuoso-specific questions are often answered more quickly and accurately on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/) or in an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Comment: i understand but it's not very practical to go to different specialized message boards

Comment: it says [here](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/) that if I have a "How do I …?" question, " Post to **Stack Overflow** or Quora!"

Comment: You're right! The what-goes-where will be edited to include what's in the body text, i.e., "The [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) is also still active."

Answer (score 3):

I stopped by this question days ago trying to achieve the same with `curl`. Since it is a powerful (and far more convenient) alternative to browser extensions, here is the formulation that eventually proved successful:

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "Content-Type:application/sparql-update" \
     -H "Accept:text/html" \
     --data "select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 100" http://localhost:8890/sparql
```

More details on the headers in [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/thread/KfF_dXPTTyjakF6oWNlzWHOAXbCxkZ4h1erB4PSxdbCe8seqxaDqGq0vyg0VyIg3j-QoooTagDhE0R660W_udXI9wEsYVGsRE463O8k3jhk%3D%40protonmail.ch/#msg37272403).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python, I would avoid using the `requests` library. There are some dedicated libraries for RDF which abstract the process and make your life easier.

Try:

- [SPARQLWrapper](https://sparqlwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)
- [RDFLib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#)

[They are both form the same family of packages from rdflib](https://rdflib.dev/)

Based on experience, I find the SPARQLWrapper significantly simpler and easier to use for your use case. It's an abstracted version of RDFLib. The docs suggest something like this could work:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, POST

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("https://example.org/sparql")
sparql.setCredentials("some-login", "some-password") # if required
sparql.setMethod(POST) # this is the crucial option

sparql.setQuery("""
    <QUERY GOES HERE>
    """.format(PARSE SOME VARS INTO THE QUERY HERE IF YOU WANT) 
)

results = sparql.query()
print results.response.read()
```

Make sure you add the option for POST. You should be doing bulk I/O in no time :).

Answer (score 0):

There are many aspects to this "question" making it difficult to provide a simple answer, suitable to this site.  This is one of the reasons I suggested the mailing list, which is better suited to conversational and/or multi-facet assistance.

- Have you tried using `curl` as most of our examples do?
- Looking at the [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) page on Mozilla Add-Ons, I see that you may need to manually add a `?` to the end of your target URI -- so `http://localhost:8890/sparql?` rather than `http://localhost:8890/sparql` -- and it's not clear whether you've done that in your testing.  On the [project page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/poster-extension/), I also note its [last commit](https://code.google.com/archive/p/poster-extension/source/default/commits) was in 2012, and there are [a great many open issues](https://code.google.com/archive/p/poster-extension/issues).
- I'm not at all familiar with Python, so I've not dug in there.
- Have you tried setting an `Accept:` header?  This can have significant impact on the content returned by the server.
- If I understand your described efforts correctly, your `format:` query parameter should be `output-format:`, and its value should not be `application/xml` but one of the supported formats [listed in the documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlprotocolendpoint/#rdfsupportedmimesofprotocolserver).
- Neither the [`virtuoso-users` post you referenced](https://www.mail-archive.com/virtuoso-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07015.html) nor this question have enough detail to analyze the cause of the `409 Invalid Path` error. Explicit details that allow us to reproduce this result would be helpful, optimally in a distinct thread.

Comment: there aren't many "aspects", the question is simple:  how to make POST work.  what you're referring as aspects are the parameters that describe my attempts

Comment: a working "hello world" for POSTing data to virtuoso would help but that's nowhere to be found

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Virtuoso specific issue. You can only post a query by using content type "application/sparql-update" instead of "application/sparql-query" which is common.

The request is done as follows with Python:

```
headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/sparql-update',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }

s = Session();
s.mount(server_url, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=1))

response: Response = s.post(server_url, data=<sparql_string>, headers=headers, timeout=100)

return response.json();
```